# kivy installation with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, kivy

this is out when i'm installing kivy with pip on cmd

```
'''
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\xeryd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\xeryd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f59y46nt\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\xeryd\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-f59y46nt\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\xeryd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-egy9la7d'
     cwd: C:\Users\xeryd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-f59y46nt\kivy\
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when trying to install kivy. Maybe the reason is you are using python 3.8 and kivy doesn't support for python 3.8 right now.
So as a solution you can install an older version of python(eg- python3.7.8) and try installing kivy. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late, but maybe someone else needs this in the Future. Try using the kivy master version. It should work upto python 3.8
`pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`